# "?" before the start of an xml file

Tags: xml

i am trying to compare 2 xml file for work and both are exactly the same except for this first line :

```
File 1: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
File 2: ﻿?﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

We can see the difference better on the picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT4Ur.png

I can't figure out what's wrong and why it does it this. I couldn't find either on the internet somebody with the same error.

Comment: What language are you using? Where's the code you used to compare them? Are you comparing them by eye and hand, written on paper? Please add a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally. One was Utf8 and the other Utf8-BOM.

Refer to this post for more understanding : [What's the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-with-bom)